# Is it appropriate to live in relative's home temporarily after marriage?

Tags: nikah

Is it allowed in Islam, as husband and wife, to stay in our mutual uncle's house during vacation when visiting home from overseas? He has 3 sons, all under 13 years of age.

Comment: Eric, Questions like this belong to sites like Quora not Stackoverflow. Your question would get flagged soon. But generally it's a complicated situation to live with relatives. The host always has the upper hand and it could make you look/feel miserable in the eyes of your wife

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have edited it, I hope it is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In islam, everything is allowed, unless explicitly made haram or makrooh. So as there is no clear prohibition in living them, then you can stay with them. (thats my personal opinion)